# Manually invoke md-autocomplete dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, md-autocomplete

When the md-autocomplete input box is first clicked, the autocomplete drop-down doesn't appear until the first character is typed. I haven't been able to figure out why the autocomplete isn't showing upon first click, as it shows in the demos.

As a workaround, is there a way to manually invoke the autocomplete functionality in a javascript method? So I could have something like:

```
<md-autocomplete ng-click="manuallyInvokingAutocomplete()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be the md-min-length equals a number larger than 0,

```
<md-autocomplete
md-min-length="0">
</md-autocomplete>
```

This solved a similar issue that I had some time ago :)